# OpenStack throws NullPointerException when connecting

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, openstack

I'm trying to connect [OpenStack](http://www.openstack.org/) before creating tenant. It gives a `NullPointerException` from `OpenStackClient.request()` in the "openstack-client-3.2.1.jar".

The code and the beginning of stack trace are as below:

```
UsernamePassword usernamePassword = new UsernamePassword(userA,passA)
com.woorea.openstack.keystone.model.Access access = 
    keystone
     .tokens()
     .authenticate(usernamePassword)
     .execute();
```

The stacktrace is:

```
 [java] java.lang.NullPointerException
 [java]     at com.woorea.openstack.base.client.OpenStackClient.request(OpenStackClient.java:51)
 [java]     at com.woorea.openstack.base.client.OpenStackClient.execute(OpenStackClient.java:66)
 [java]     at com.woorea.openstack.base.client.OpenStackRequest.execute(OpenStackRequest.java:98)
 [java]     at vep.openstack.OpenStackConnector.addUser(OpenStackConnector.java:624)
```

Comment: I looked at the source files of the package and tracing from the stack, the exception occurs while executing the line 51 in com.woorea.openstack.base.client.OpenStackClient:    
`return connector.request(request);`

Probably the variable 'connector' of type 'OpenStackClientConnector connector' doesn't get initialized before which I might need to do probably.

Ref source of the jar [http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.woorea/openstack-client/3.2.1/com/woorea/openstack/base/client/OpenStackClient.java#OpenStackClient.execute%28com.woorea.openstack.base.client.OpenStackRequest%29]

Answer (score 1):

It was required to add one of the three libraries (i.e. openstack-client-connectors) listed below:

jersey-connector

jersey2-connector

resteasy-connector

Answer (score 0):

The variable `userA` is null. You need to properly initialize it.

Comment: No. Both are holding the proper values. I just checked. Thanks for pointing out a possibility which I didn't notice.